# Why can't I create a new issue tracking list alert with a daily or weekly digest?

Tags: 2007, alert, configuration, issue-tracking

A site owner in my site collection created a new Issue Tracking list from the default list template, then added a handful of custom columns from the default list of available column types.

When they try to create an alert, by going to Actions -> Alert Me the **When to Send Alerts** option only shows *Send e-mail immediately* without the other email digest options like "Send a daily summary" or "Send a weekly summary" and the time.

I have created a new Issue Tracking list in the same site and the alerts options are all there.  I have created a new Issue Tracking list in a different site and all the options are there.  I have not recreated the 7 custom columns.

I have poked around in a lot of the list settings, but nothing is standing out.  Where should I be looking and what should I be looking for to enable the digest emails?

Comment: As an alternate answer, give a link to Google that can address this.  So far every query I try is about how to create alerts.  I cannot find the wording to get what I want.

Comment: I have tried doing all sorts of this to try and replicate this. I have not had any luck. If you could post additional details about specific version, if you are using custom templates please post the xml for it (powershell dump or xml from the template file). Also, What are the custom columns you have added?

Are you able to recreate the issue in a new Site Collection?

Comment: We dumped the library and started over, things worked.  I assumed the library was corrupt somehow.

Comment: Add that as the answer and select it!